# Combine conversion from model to viewModel gives error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when running .eraseToAnyPublisher()

Tags: ios, swift, combine, publisher

I am trying to figure out why the last .eraseToAnyPublisher() is giving the aforementioned error, to me it seems all the types are well specified, aren't they?

```
static func searchUsers(query: String) -> AnyPublisher<[UserViewModel], Never> {
            // prepare URL
            let urlString = "\(baseURL)/search/users?q=\(query)"
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else  {
                return Just([]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            // get handle of native data task publisher
            let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .handleEvents(
                    receiveSubscription: { _ in
                        activityIndicatorPublisher.send(true)
                    }, receiveCompletion: { _ in
                        activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
                    }, receiveCancel: {
                        activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
                    })
                .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                          httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                              throw NetworkError.httpError
                          }
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
                    return data
                }
                .decode(type: SearchUserResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .map { $0.items }
                .flatMap({ users in
                    var userViewModels = [UserViewModel]()
                    users.forEach { user in
                        userViewModels.append(contentsOf: UserViewModel(with: user))
                    }
                    return userViewModels
                })
                .catch { err -> Just<[UserViewModel]> in
                    print(err)
                    return Just([])
                }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher() // <-- HERE IS THE ERROR
            return publisher
        }
```

Comment: Take a look in your guard statement at the top of the function.  You've got a Just([]) but I don't think you're defining the type there.  That could be the problem.

Comment: Thank you @DPrice but that is not the problem, the line was there even before I was returning an array of User instances, returning a publisher with an empty array is fine. Should be something else.

Comment: Don't you just need `map` instead of `flatMap`?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa maybe you are right, but can you elaborate? How do I map [User] in [UserViewModel] in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with those complex `Combine` pipelines sometimes compliler errors are displayed on the wrong line. In your case there are two problems, but not where the compiler is pointing.

One being use of `flatMap` instead of `map`.

This part of the pipeline:

```
let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .handleEvents(
        receiveSubscription: { _ in
            activityIndicatorPublisher.send(true)
        }, receiveCompletion: { _ in
            activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
        }, receiveCancel: {
            activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
        })
        .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
             guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                 httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                 throw NetworkError.httpError
             }
             print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
             return data
        }
        .decode(type: SearchUserResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map { $0.items }
```

returns `Publisher<[User], Error>`.

Next you want to transforming that into `Publisher<[UserViewModel], Error>` for which you need a function `map`:

```
func map<T>(_ transform: @escaping (Output) -> T) -> Publishers.Map<Upstream, T>
```

which transforms one type of `Output` into another type of `Output` not `flatMap`:

```
func flatMap<T, P>(maxPublishers: Subscribers.Demand = .unlimited, _ transform: @escaping (Self.Output) -> P) -> Publishers.FlatMap<P, Self> where T == P.Output, P : Publisher, Self.Failure == P.Failure
```

which transforms `Output` into a new `Publisher`

The second problem is with `append(contentsOf;)` which expects a `Sequence` of elements, in case of single elements you should use `append()`, but even simpler would be just to map the `[User]` to `[UserViewModel]`:

```
{ users in
    users.map { user in
        UserViewModel(with: user)
    }
}
```

so the whole function should work with those changes:

```
static func searchUsers(query: String) -> AnyPublisher<[UserViewModel], Never> {
    // prepare URL
    let urlString = "\(baseURL)/search/users?q=\(query)"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else  {
        return Just([]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    // get handle of native data task publisher
    let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .handleEvents(
            receiveSubscription: { _ in
                activityIndicatorPublisher.send(true)
            }, receiveCompletion: { _ in
                activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
            }, receiveCancel: {
                activityIndicatorPublisher.send(false)
            })
        .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                      throw NetworkError.httpError
                  }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            return data
        }
        .decode(type: SearchUserResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map { $0.items }
        .map { users in
            users.map { user in
                UserViewModel(with: user)
            }
        }
        .catch { err -> Just<[UserViewModel]> in
            print(err)
            return Just([])
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    return publisher
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and even more for the thorough explanation!!!